# No notification of a comment on an answer to my question

Tags: support, comments, notifications, global-inbox

I didn't receive any notifications on the comments to [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/29229/i-got-pets-i-didnt-ask-for/29230#29230) to a question of mine. Aren't the question owners supposed to be notified of these as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No -- per

https://gaming.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

> **The owner of the post you're commenting on will always be notified of your comment. If you are replying to someone else who has previously commented on the same post, mention their username:** @peter and @PeterSmith will both notify a previous commenter named “Peter Smith”.

Thus, in graphical form -- the red arrows indicate who is notified for each comment:

[image]

Comment: I see... I thought that was different before. Wouldn't it make more sense though? If I accept an answer and someone makes a comment that proves the answer wrong I'd like to know about that without having to rely on the commenter remembering to @notify me as well...

Comment: could this be made available [as an option](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104705/option-to-subscribe-to-notifications-on-a-specific-posts-comments)?

Answer (score 1):

By design, comments to *answers* don't notify the *question* owner; see also [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)