# Option to subscribe to notifications on a specific posts comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, notifications, usability

Since some useful answers to other's questions sometimes later turn out be be wrong or receive comments that can provide valuable additional information, it would be great to be able to subscribe to comment-notifications on individual posts (that one doesn't own) instead of having to favourite the entire question. Maybe even with some noise filter like "only notify me of comments with at least [n] great comment votes" option.

This would also be useful to allow subscribing to the currently accepted answer to ones own questions, since [there is no notification of comments to that unless @addressed to you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104691/no-notification-of-a-comment-on-an-answer-to-my-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), with the [rollout of the Followed Questions feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network):

> After you have followed a post, you will get inbox notifications for all new answers (in the case where you followed a question), comments, edits, and notices.